# On creating a JAR in android studio, how to add the external jar library in the module?

Tags: java, android, jar

On creating a jar for android application, i tried pulling up some external jar's in the module.but each time i try to build the jar im facing this issue.

Error:Execution failed for task ':mpos:compileJava'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>   Error:(9, 19) error: package android.app does not exist
>   Error:(14, 30) error: cannot find symbol class Activity

"mpos" is my file name.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your JAR file in `app/libs`, and in `app/build.gradle` inside the dependencies section:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put your jar files in any directory you want to make inside module like `app` module or your `library` module
then you add an implementation command in build.gradle file of that module and specify the jar directories you made. like this

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

or maybe

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'path/to/dir')
```